# SQL Server sort data with Order By according to current date

Tags: sql-server, date, select, sql-order-by, sql-server-2019

I have a table `WebOrder`
Below is a simplified version of the table (I omitted most of the columns that weren't necessary for this post)

```
+-------------------+----------------+
|Field              |Type            |
+-------------------+----------------+
|WebOrderID         |Int             |
|DueDate            |Date            |
|Customer           |nvarchar(50)    |
+-------------------+----------------+
```

I would like to sort by due date which is easy enough with

```
SELECT * FROM WebOrder ORDER BY DueDate
```

However I would like to take that sorting a step further and have WebOrders that are due on the current date to display at the top, followed WebOrders that are due at a later date, and finally have the later due dates followed by past due dates.
Below is an example of what the output would look like

```
+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+
|WebOrderID         |DueDate         |Customer         |
+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+
|23                 |2020-06-24      |Phillip Fry      |
|2                  |2020-06-24      |Karen Clay       |
|35                 |2020-06-26      |George Sun       |
|64                 |2020-06-28      |Austin Powers    |
|1                  |2020-06-01      |Wu Lang          |
|12                 |2020-06-05      |Jessica Myers    |
|6                  |2020-06-07      |Sarah Red        |
+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

This post was very similar to what I wanted to achieve, [Sorting data according to current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201143/sorting-data-according-to-current-date), however I wasn't sure how to achieve the same thing in sql server.
This is my first post so let me know how I can improve my question and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a conditional sort:

```
order by
    case 
        when dueDate = cast(getdate() as date) then 0
        when dueDate > cast(getdate() as date) then 1
        else 2
    end,
    dueDate
```

The first expression in the `order by` clause gives priority to record on the current date, then to future records. The second sorting criteria sorts then subsets by `dueDate`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That worked perfectly. I really appreciate it.